# Changing the title of New/Edit/Display form in CSOM

Tags: csom, form, client-side-rendering

How I can change the title of list's form?
The following code does not work:

```
$("#dialogTitleSpan").text("New title")
```

UPDATED

I found acceptable solution. I use MutationObserver for tracking changes in title node and after changes has done I change title to desirable value.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the page title of specific page using "**PlaceHolderPageTitle**" placeholder.

Please refer following Steps:

1. Open Your New/Edit/Display item form.
2. Search for "PlaceHolderPageTitle"
3. Specify the name you want for this form (refer below image: here "New Title" is the name I have specified for title this form)

   [image]

Please let me know if you face any problem.

Comment: I am need to solve my problem using only client side code.

Comment: In this case please try this --> SP.UI.UIUtility.setInnerText(parent.document.getElementById("dialogTitleSpan"), "New Title");

Answer (score 1):

Use the below code :

```
var options =
    {
        title: 'Title', //add whatever title you want       
        url: 'your modal url',
        height: 400,
        width: 300
    }

    SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options);
```

Comment: I don't open list forms explicitly to set these parameters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to change the title of the Forms, just put below line in forms :

```
document.title = "New Item / Edit Item / Display Item ";
```

Hope, you got your answer :)

Comment: My forms open in modal dialog mode, document.title do not affects the form in this case.

Comment: Well for that.. you can check this link.. https://mywaysharepoint.wordpress.com/2015/05/23/change-title-of-new-edit-view-list-form/

Answer (score 0):

I guess can't do that with CSOM client side object model

i think SP.dll or spjs.js can make below code:

find

```
<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderId="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
```

insert below tags in it

```
<h1 style="font-family:'b nazanin' "> Title </h1>
```

Comment: The question is asking how to do it in CSOM ..